# Impossible to read queue message with Masstransit

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

I have a queue with some messages in (created with masstransit).

I tried this piece of code the get the messages (see below).

I expected to get the messages on the Console.Out line but I never hit this line and the messages are still in the queue. I didn't get any error.

Any idea ?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
    
                cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });
    
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", e =>
                {
                    e.Handler<ProcessingQueue>(context =>
                    {
                        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{context.Message.Id}");
                    });
    
                });
    
            });
        }
    }
    
    public class ProcessingQueue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks,

I tried to add :

```
bus.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Receive listening for messages");
Console.ReadLine();
bus.Stop();
```

but when I do this a new queue is created `myQueue_skipped` is created with my messages in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If messages are moved to the *_skipped* queue, it indicates that those messages are not consumed by any of the consumers configured on that receive endpoint. The most common mistake, [as highlighted at the top of the message documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html), is a mismatched namespace.

Similar answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529896/1882)

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's work. Bonus question : I have a queue with 100 messages in. I'd like, in some cases, send a message but this message should be treated, first, in priority, before the existing 100. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You're welcome to ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code for the ReceiveEndpoint

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("myQueue", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<MessagesConsumer>();
});
```

"MessagesConsumer" must inherit from IConsumer

```
public class MessagesConsumer: IConsumer<ProcessingQueue>      
{   public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProcessingQueue> context)
        {
             //access to the properties
             var name=context.Message.Name;
             var id=context.Message.Id;
        }
}
```

In the Consume method, you will receive messages of the type "ProcessingQueue". You can access the properties here..